# check constaint to user defined type (not table) in sql server

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types, check-constraints

It possible to create an user-defined type with check constaint?

somethins like:

```
create type json from nvarchar(max) check isjson(value)=1
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a user defined type with constraint as you have mentioned. you can define a table type with columns containing CHECK constraint. [Read on CREATE TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

If you want to define for a column type,as suggested by you, sp_bind might be removed in future. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-bindrule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I would suggest you to define check constraint and utilize the IsJSon() function in the check constraint as given below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestJson
(
DocumentId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
JsonText VARCHAR(max) CHECK (IsJson(JsonText) =1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I can add a rule.

```
create rule json_rule
as
    isjson(@range) = 1

GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.[json] FROM nvarchar(max) NULL

GO

EXEC sys.sp_bindrule @rulename=N'[dbo].[json_rule]', @objname=N'[dbo].[json]' , @futureonly='futureonly'
```